# Print character n times based on column value

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to print the character "N" multiple times, based on the value of a column in several lines of a table

For example, the output of this table:

```
AATTGGCC   A   1.7   4
CCGGTTAA   T   0.8   3
AAGGTTCC   G   2.4   7
```

Would ideally return:

```
NNNN
NNN
NNNNNNN
```

based on the value in column 4.

Currently, I have been using:

```
while read line
do
a=$4
printf "$0.sN\n" {a}
done < table.txt
```

But this only returns three 'N's, each on new lines.
Ideally I would also like to print out the letter from column 2 on the end of each line of output.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off the example you gave, I would change it to this:

```
while read line
do
    a=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $4}')
    printf "N%.0s" $(seq $a)
    echo
done < table.txt
```

It's not clear to me how you were able to get the 3 N's from your original solution (I could not reproduce), but maybe we have a different configuration. The solution I posted above is based on BASH. Inside the while loop, the first line of code,

```
    a=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $4}')
```

echos the line then pipes it into an awk statement that only looks at the fourth column and saves it to a variable called "a". The `$(...)` notation simply means to evaluate the statement within the parenthesis as a BASH command (in this case an `echo` piped into an `awk` command). On the second line,

```
    printf "N%.0s" $(seq $a)
```

I print out $a number of Ns via the `printf` command. Once again, the `$(...)` simply runs the BASH command, which in this case is a `seq` command to print $a characters. With this in a script, I was able to get the following result for your example table.txt file:

```
NNNN
NNN
NNNNNNN
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash:

```
while read x x x end; do
  for ((i=0; i<$end; i++)); do
    echo -n "N"
  done
  echo
done < file
```

Output:

```
NNNN
NNN
NNNNNNN
```